# HTML + JS How to change/unchange text onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to write a JS that changes text on a button when clicked (to 'SHOW'), but when another button is clicked then the previously clicked button will change its text from 'SHOW' to initial text (eg 'A')
Scenario:
1. click on button A -> 'A' changes to 'SHOW'
2. click on button B -> 'B' changes to 'SHOW' but also 'SHOW'(from button A) changes back to 'A'

```
<button id="button1" value="A">A</button>
<button id="button2" value="B">B</button>
<button id="button3" value="C">C</button>
```

Above you will find example buttons i have in html file.
In JS file i have:

```
$("button1").on('click', function () {
    $('.btn_click').removeClass('btn_click');//this is a css class that changes bg color
    $(this).addClass('btn_click');
    $(this).text('SHOW');
});
```

previously i used class selector not id one, but still could not accomplish what i wanted. The add and remove CSS works really ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have your solution, because when you add a class to the last pressed button, you can use it to change the text back:

```
$("button").on('click', function () {
    $('.btn_click')
        .text($('.btn_click').val())
        .removeClass('btn_click');//this is a css class that changes bgcolor
    $(this).addClass('btn_click');
    $(this).text('SHOW');
});
```

Comment: How does this change the value on Button A to 'A' when Button B is clicked?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var clicked_button = $(this);
 $("button").each(function() {
    if($(this).is(clicked_button)) {
      $(this).text('SHOW');
      
    }
    else {
     $(this).text($(this).attr('value'))
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1" value="A">A</button>
    <button id="button2" value="B">B</button>
    <button id="button3" value="C">C</button>
```

Check working example here https://jsfiddle.net/prxd81vk/

Answer (score 1):

You must use `$("#button1")` to properly select the button by id. This `onClick` is not actually associated to any of the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep track of the old text of the button and revert back to it when another button is pressed.

Example:

```js
    $("button").on('click', function () {
      $('.btn_click').removeClass('btn_click');//this is a css class that changes bg color
      $("[data-old-text]").each(function () {
        $(this).text($(this).attr("data-old-text"));
          $(this).removeAttr("data-old-text");
      }); 
      $(this).addClass('btn_click');
      $(this).attr("data-old-text", $(this).text());
      $(this).text('SHOW');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">A</button>
<button id="button2">B</button>
<button id="button3">C</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select element by ID you must use `$("#button1")`.

Try like this:

```
$("#button1").on('click', function () {
 $('.btn_click').removeClass('btn_click');//this is a css class that changes bg color
 $(this).addClass('btn_click');
 $(this).text('SHOW');
});
```

And after that add whatever you want to do with other two buttons (set A,B,C).

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

Button 1 click :

```
 $('#button1').click(function () {
        $('#button1').text('Show');
    });
```

Buttton 2 click :

```
 $('#button2').click(function () {
        $('#button2').text('show');
        $('#button1').text('old value');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change targeting elements from `id` to `class` attribute.

```
<button class="button" value="A">A</button>
<button class="button" value="B">B</button>
<button class="button" value="C">C</button>
```

The script would then first clear the 'btn_click' class from any other buttons, and then apply the 'active' class to the button that was clicked.

```
$("button").on('click', function () {
$('.button').removeClass('btn_click');//this is a css class that changes bg color
$(this).addClass('btn_click');
$(this).text('SHOW');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try this code..    

<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       $('#button1').click(function()
       {
       $('.btn_click').removeClass('btn_click');//this is a css class that changes bg color
    $(this).addClass('btn_click');
       $(this).text('Show');
        $('#button2').text('B');
       });

       $('#button2').click(function()
       {
       $('#button1').text('A');
        $(this).text('Show');
       });

       });
    </script>
```